# LateInitializationError: Field '_stepRepo@870166190' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I use `AsyncNotifier` and I know that `build()` method is the method to initialize AsyncNotifier.

So I have used build method to initialed all, especially `late` var so far and it works fine.

However I keep facing here, LateInitializationError even though I initialize `_stepRepo` in build.

```
class StepViewModel extends AsyncNotifier<void> {
  late final StepRepository _stepRepo;

  @override
  FutureOr<void> build() {
    _stepRepo = ref.read(stepRepo);
  }

  Future<int> fetchUserTodayStepcountVM() async {
    int todayStepCount = await _stepRepo.fetchUserTodayStepCount();
    return todayStepCount;
  }
}

final stepProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<StepViewModel, void>(
  () => StepViewModel(),
);
```

[image]

I call this `Notifier` in background service like below.

```
class StepBackgroundService {
  ...
  final stepProvider = StepViewModel();
    int? todayStep = await stepProvider.fetchUserTodayStepcountVM();
    ...
}
```